# Immediately cancel python asyncio task when all tasks are waiting

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

It appears that the python event loop will do nothing until internally something has work to be done. This means that cancelling tasks won't actually do anything until one of the tasks wakes up and begins executing.

SSCCE:

```py
import asyncio
import signal
import time

start_time = time.time()
task1 = None
task2 = None


async def wait(name, duration):
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(duration)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print(f"{name} got cancellation ({(time.time() - start_time):.2})")
        pass


async def main():
    global task1
    global task2
    task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(wait("task1", 5))
    task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(wait("taks2", 10))

    await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)


def run():
    def handle_signal(a, b):
        print(f"cancelling main task ({(time.time() - start_time):.2})")
        task1.cancel()
        task2.cancel()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_signal)

    asyncio.run(main())
    print('done')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Output:

```
$ python3.7 async.py 
^Ccancelling main task (0.88)
task1 got cancellation (5.0)
taks2 got cancellation (5.0)
done
```

How can I force the event loop to cancel those tasks immediately, without waiting for one to wake up from sleep?

Using python3.6 and python3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm leaving the old content of this answer up as a demonstration of techniques that can be used when working with signal handlers, but it turns out asyncio actually has its own signal handling API.

[`loop.add_signal_handler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#unix-signals) can be used to set asyncio-compatible signal handlers. These will be invoked under the control of the event loop, and unlike normal signal handlers, they can safely interact with the event loop. (Note that this means the event loop has to wait for any currently executing coroutine to yield control before the loop can run signal handlers.) Signal handlers set through this API should take no arguments, unlike regular signal handlers.

If you remove the arguments from your signal handler's definition and set the handler with `asyncio.get_event_loop().add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, handle_signal)`, it'll just work. Actually, it'd be better to set the handler from `main` after creating the tasks, and use `asyncio.get_running_loop()`:

```
def handle_signal():
    print(f"cancelling main task ({(time.time() - start_time):.2})")
    task1.cancel()
    task2.cancel()

async def main():
    global task1
    global task2
    task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(wait("task1", 5))
    task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(wait("taks2", 10))

    asyncio.get_running_loop().add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, handle_signal)

    await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)
```

What follows is the old answer, which gets the job done through the normal signal handling API rather than asyncio's API, because I didn't know asyncio had a signal API when I wrote it.

---

You've got two primary problems here.

Problem 1 is that trying to directly cancel tasks from within a signal handler is already unsafe. Signal handlers can run while `asyncio` is doing internal work and its data structures are in an inconsistent state. This kind of issue is even worse than concurrency issues, because locking does nothing to fix it. There is very little you can safely do inside a signal handler.

Problem 2 is that `task.cancel()` arranges for a `CancelledError` to be thrown into the wrapped coroutine *on the next iteration of the event loop*. You need something to trigger an iteration of the event loop.

---

One of the most complex and useful things you can do in a Python signal handler is send messages through a [`queue.SimpleQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#simplequeue-objects). This is a synchronization queue that trades limited functionality for the ability to safely call its `put` method in precarious conditions like `__del__` methods, weakref callbacks, and other code that might interrupt complex operations in the same thread.

`queue.SimpleQueue.get` isn't async-compatible, so the code that receives the message will have to be in another thread. That thread can't safely call `cancel` either, because only very limited parts of asyncio are designed to be threadsafe, and `Task.cancel` isn't one of the parts documented as threadsafe. In fact, the second sentence of `asyncio.Task`'s documentation is "Not thread-safe."

However, you can have a task run a function in a thread with `loop.run_in_executor`, and have that function receive the cancellation message from the queue. The task can wait for that function to finish, and then safely perform the cancellation from inside the event loop. Another iteration of the event loop will then run as soon as the canceller task finishes, and the tasks you want cancelled will be cancelled.

```
import asyncio
import queue
import signal
import time

start_time = time.time()
task1 = None
task2 = None

cancel_queue = queue.SimpleQueue()

async def wait(name, duration):
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(duration)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print(f"{name} got cancellation ({(time.time() - start_time):.2})")
        pass

async def canceller_task():
    do_cancel = await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None, receive_cancel_message)
    if do_cancel:
        task1.cancel()
        task2.cancel()

def receive_cancel_message():
    return cancel_queue.get()

def handle_signal(a, b):
    cancel_queue.put(True)

async def main():
    global task1
    global task2
    task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(wait("task1", 5))
    task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(wait("taks2", 10))
    task3 = asyncio.ensure_future(canceller_task())

    await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)

    # End canceller_task and receive_cancel_message even if the signal
    # handler didn't fire.
    # May leave an extra False in the queue if the signal handler fired.
    # That's okay.
    cancel_queue.put(False)
    await task3


def run():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_signal)

    asyncio.run(main())
    print('done')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: Hi, this behavior is demonstrated using a signal handler but has nothing to do with signal handling. It is irrelevant where the cancellation comes from, the point is that the cancellation will not occur until work is done in the event loop. The question is how to make the cancellation occur immediately.

Comment: @MirroredFate: A task periodically checking the cancellation flag will perform cancellation as soon as the canceller task suspends.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are saying. Could you ignore the fact that a signal handler is involved and just post some code to demonstrate? If I follow what you're saying, the task cancellation will still rely on something internal to the task performing a poll loop (flag checking) which effectively gates the cancellation.

Comment: @MirroredFate: No, a separate task would be checking the flag. The problem with trying to ignore the signal handler is that the answer to your question is completely different based on how and where your cancellation is happening, and signal handling in particular imposes strict limitations.

Comment: For large, complex application, sure. For small demonstration purposes, it makes no difference.
Or, you really think it does, please write some code that demonstrates the different approaches.
Basically your answer so far boils down to "don't do that" and no example of _how_ to do it. Not very useful.

Comment: @MirroredFate: I've edited my answer with a slightly different approach and example code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It really helps explain things. Just a note, SimpleQueue was apparently introduced in 3.7, so for my use case I validated this with just a Queue and it was perfectly functional.

Comment: You can use `loop.add_signal_handler()` to register a handler that will be [safe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.add_signal_handler) to itneract with the event loop. Then you can `put_nowait` into an `asyncio.Queue` and avoid the need for `run_in_executor`.

Comment: @user4815162342: Well that's a lot more convenient. I didn't know about that function.

Comment: @user4815162342: Do we still need the queue for some reason? It looks like we should be able to just cancel the tasks directly from the signal handler if we go through the asyncio signal API.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to put effort into this answer, it has really helped. I think it's probably the best succinct example of how to manage asyncio cancellation and signals out there.